# Tasks and Binding works but every now and then I get an error out of the blue

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a learning application and

I'm trying to make a simple animation using Dispachtimer and an Image control.  I have 3 images that I jump through every 100 ms.  Everything works great but after some time passes I get this error.

I notice that when I decrease the time interval the garbage collector doesn't fire as often.  I'm new to WPF and would love to wrap my brain around whats happening.   Once again, the animation does work for a random amount of time.

**

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

**

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) subscribed to the event
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ImageSource _imageSourceHeader_Image;
    public ImageSource ImageSourceHeader_Image 
    {
    get
        {
            return _imageSourceHeader_Image;
        }
    set
        {
            _imageSourceHeader_Image = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSourceHeader_Image");
        }
     }        

    public ViewModel()
    {
        StartAnimationAsync();

    }

    public void StartAnimationAsync()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    int i = 1;
    private async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
           if (i < 4 )
            {

                ImageSourceHeader_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg"));

                ImageSourceHeader_Image.Freeze();                   
            }
            else
            {
                i = 1;
                ImageSourceHeader_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg"));

                ImageSourceHeader_Image.Freeze();

            }
            i = i + 1;

        });

    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Haven't worked with WPF, but the reason to do dispatch timer here is to use the UI thread which is the only place to interact with the ui components. Try removing the async params, the reason for randomness is probably that async doesnt always spin out a new thread.

Comment: @SumitMaingi is right. If I were you, I would remove the async-await from the `timer_Tick` method completely. It has to run on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: When I do that my app because very glitchy like it stuck in a thread.

Comment: Never mind, that fixed the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
           if (i < 4 )
            {

                ImageSourceHeader_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg"));

                ImageSourceHeader_Image.Freeze();                   
            }
            else
            {
                i = 1;
                ImageSourceHeader_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg"));

                ImageSourceHeader_Image.Freeze();

            }
            i = i + 1;

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run` executes code on a background thread. Specifically, the code creating the `BitmapImage`.

You need to create all UI objects (including `BitmapImage`) on the UI thread:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (i < 4 )
  {
    ImageSourceHeader_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg"));
    ImageSourceHeader_Image.Freeze();                   
  }
  else
  {
    i = 1;
    ImageSourceHeader_Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg"));
    ImageSourceHeader_Image.Freeze();
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
```

It's probably a better idea to load them *all* into `BitmapImage`s one time, and then just switch between them when the timer fires.